# Maintain central header in deeper directories

Tags: php

On my site within `/public_html` I have a file called `/public_html/header.php`. This file is called on every page using;

`<?php echo file_get_contents("./header.php"); ?>`

which works for any pages within the `/public_html` directory.

Same goes for the index page of the blog at `/public_html/blog/` and its index page. It just uses;

`<?php echo file_get_contents("../header.php"); ?>`

instead. The issue arises when including the header within the articles subdirectory at `/public_html/blog/articles/ariclename.php`. I'd tried;

`<?php echo file_get_contents(".../header.php"); ?>`

but that doesn't work. I've also tried different `./././`, `../../../` combinations but can't seem to get it to work.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have a config file, like config.php?

Comment: I have options within cPanel but no config file. I just don't understand why it works two directories deep but not three?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constant to set your path globally across all your pages.

This is how you would do that.

Create a file to configure the constant with the path to the header.

config.php

```
<?php

  define('MY_HEADER', 'full/path/to/header.php');

?>
```

Generally you want to include the config.php in a file that gets called every time your script loads so that it always gets called.

In a file that gets called every time your script loads you would require your `config.php` file like so.

```
require 'path/to/config.php';
```

Then on any page where you need to use `header.php` all you need to do to get the header is this:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents(MY_HEADER); ?>
```